# Getting json data works in IE but not FF and Chrome

Tags: javascript, json, model-view-controller

It seems one of the JSON requests in my mvc app fails when using Firefox but works on IE (and this part seems to work in chrome as well). I thought it might be due to the same-origin policy, but according to my understanding it shouldn't cause any trouble, as all requests use the same host and protocol (in this situation, localhost). When i checked the requests in the net functions of firefox, ie and chrome debuggers, it seems the request made by IE and Chrome is answered with 270b, while the FF request gets only 2b. Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
$(function () {
    // this seems to work fine in FF and IE
    var IncludeTerminatedFlag = getIncludeTerminatedFlag();
    $.getJSON("/Search/GetDebtorList", { DebtorNameCode: '', CountryCode: CountryCode, IncludeTerminatedFlag: IncludeTerminatedFlag }, function (data) {
       // some actions
    });
    // this works fine in FF and IE
    $.getJSON("/Search/GetStaffList", { StaffNameCode: '', CountryCode: CountryCode, IncludeTerminatedFlag: IncludeTerminatedFlag }, function (data) {
        // some actions
    });
    // this works fine in FF and IE
    $.getJSON("/Search/GetStaffList", { StaffNameCode: '', CountryCode: CountryCode, IncludeTerminatedFlag: IncludeTerminatedFlag }, function (data) {
       // some actions
    });

    // this does not work in FF but works in IE
    $.getJSON("/Search/GetClientList", { ClientNameCode: '', CountryCode: CountryCode, IncludeTerminatedFlag: IncludeTerminatedFlag }, function (data) {
      // some actions
    });

}
```

EDIT: When i tried to debug it under firefox, it seems the laston getJSON call fails? as in it does not go inside the funcion. It also does not work when I try the $ajax syntax

Comment: We can't make a sure answer without knowing what is being returned by the GetClientList path on the server.

Comment: Check for errors on the server side, or add some debugging code there to see what is happening. If you only get 2 bytes back, that is where you should look next.

Comment: @trincot I added some edit info. How do I check for errors on the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON being returned could be not properly formatted(Chrome is very strict). Try adding error catching to see what the error is in Chrome

```
$.getJSON("/Search/GetDebtorList", { DebtorNameCode: '', CountryCode: CountryCode, IncludeTerminatedFlag: IncludeTerminatedFlag }, function (data) {
   // some actions
})
.error(function(data) {
  console.log("Error: " + data);
});
```

Comment: there was no chrome error, but it helped me find the firefox error. It was inside the function, where I was changing the button. No idea why when I am debugging using firefox, it just skips the whole content of the function inside getJSON.